# SSIS task to copy MDF and LDF files in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssis-2012

My requirement: I have a task to copy MDF and LDF of a one of the development DB from the E drive on the server to a shared folder on network. I have scheduled a jobs to detach the DB 1st of every month. Is there any way i can schedule a task or a use a ssis package to copy this MDF and LDF files to a shared folder on network. i could use a sql job or a windows task than a SSIS package. Thank You.

Comment: why not a do a nightly backup?

Comment: i need to keep the MDF and LDF file on email. i am not restoring them on other serve

Comment: does not make sense.. in the backup file you get to keep them together and it's a lot smaller (compressed) than the actual database.. and normally you don't email it but ftp.

Comment: MDF and LDF in an email, don't do it, when the sh!t hit the fan, its your neck on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will be using these MDF and LDF files to create the same database on some other server.

Instead of detaching database and moving MDF and LDF files I would suggest you to take a backup of the database and move that backup file across the network.

Benefits:

1. Using compression, the size of the backup file could be a lot smaller compare to the MDF and LDF files.
2. Instead of using SSIS, a SQL Agent job can take that backup for you on a network share.
3. To reduce the pressure on network you can take a backup on multiple files and move them multiple relatively smaller files across the network.
4. For security you can also encrypt your backup.
5. You can use SSIS to take a backup and move across the network again all of the above applies to that backup too (security, network load etc)

Basically moving a backup file is much more efficient and safer than using detach and attach method to move databases across the network.

Attach and detach method is also good but only when you are staying on the same server.

*Answer to your question is, yes you can detach and attach using SSIS but dont do it, because of all the reasons mentioned above.*

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a nightly backup as both files (mdf and ldf) are kept together and smaller than the actual database if you compress it. (100gb database will be around about 4gb when backup is compressed)
2. do not email but use ftp or of some sort.

In my years of administering database I have not come across copying mdf and ldf files apart from relocating to another server by detach and attach.